# версия opengl в sdl2

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengles, sdl2

Вот так работает и отображает всё на экране.

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24 );
```

Я использую эту версию opengl, а шейдеры делаю `400`. Можно ли так? Или может есть более правильный способ. Как то не очень понятно, почему в sdl2 нет поддержки opengl 4.

Comment: В SDL есть поддержка OpenGl 4.  Вы его случаем не путаете с OpenGL ES (у которого максимальная версия 3.2)? Более правильный способ - не использовать SDL.

Comment: @user7860670 почему не использовать? Я только сегодня разобрался с тем, чтобы вывести и текст и спрайты и 3d модельки на android. А 4 версию мне например надо для персонального компьютера. А как выбрать 4 версию? У меня почему то не работала.

Comment: На андроиде OpenGL ES. На практике выходит, что набор костылей, предоставляемый SDL все равно приходится самостоятельно докостыливать. Например на том же андроиде разработка только через NDK (т.е. NativeActivity без java / jni) в SDL не реализована.